# PHP Loop executing on top of each other

Tags: php, html, css

It should be like this:

```
<div> code here </div>
<div> code here </div>
<div> code here </div>
```

Each div looping right after the other.  Instead, it is executing like this:

```
 <div> code here </div>
      <div> code here </div>
           <div> code here </div>
```

Page I am working on: http://www.equitasmg.com/who-we-are-2/

The images are not aligned (should be in a row).

Here's the PHP:

```
 <center><h2>Our Leadership</h2></center>
 <?php
 $people= get_field('people');
 $a=0;
 foreach ($people as $r) {
$a++;
?>
          <div style="float:left;width:30%;padding:30px;">
            <img src="<?php echo $r['image']['sizes']['team'];?>" style="max-width:750px !important;width:250px;">
            <h3>
                <?php echo $r['name'];?>
            </h3>
            <div class="position">
                <?php echo $r['position'];?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $r['intro_text'];?>
            <?php if ($r[ 'learn_more_text']) { ?>
            <a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>">Learn More</a>
            <?php } ?>
 <?php if ($r[ 'learn_more_text']) { ?>
 <div id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

<h3><?php echo $r['name'];?></h3>
<div class="position">
    <?php echo $r['position'];?>
</div>
<div class="content">       
<?php echo $r['learn_more_text'];?>
</div>
<a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
 </div>
        </div>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: There are a number of issues with your HTML and CSS. This isn't just you outputting the HTML tags wrong, you also have inline CSS that is messing up too. The only help I can offer you now is this: Open Google Chrome, inspect your elements. Play with your HTML and CSS by re-organizing the HTML and modifying your CSS. Do that until you have a fixed version of your page. Then look at how you are outputting it with PHP and fix that accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem one div should between closing php tag

```
 <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
 </div>     
 <?php } ?>
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped!  But now, there are 2 images that are separated in 2 different rows.  No idea why.

Comment: its because your image height is not same try putting same height for all images

Comment: and also the height of  this div   <div id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>"

Comment: i mean that the height of div wrapping single content should be same as other content

Comment: Question: I am trying to make the page mobile responsive.  I can't put a fixed height on each content div.  If I put "auto" or a percentage for the height, the images break into 2 different rows.  They only become aligned if they have a fixed height.  Any reason why it does this?

Comment: you can use media query or you can change the font size so that the position will be displayed in a single line

Comment: but why does the first 3 images align in a row and not the rest of the images in that section?  then in the next section below, all images are aligned in rows.

Comment: this sentence "Senior Vice President of Real Estate and Development " is taking up more space below than other and the button

Comment: If I try to wrap all of the content divs into one div, it refuses to and only one item is wrapped.  Though the bottom section seems to be able to have a div wrapped around it.

Comment: Can’t get what you are saying

Comment: Look at the "Our Leadership" section at http://www.equitasmg.com/who-we-are-2/.  Look at the source code.  You will notice all of the images are wrapped in a <center> tag.  There is a <div> after the <center> tag but that div tag only wraps around the first image in the section.  It should be wrapping around the entire section, not just one image.

Comment: this div should also be inside foreach loop wrapping all the content

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to float every div in loop just add a div before loop and float that div to left. 
remove floating Style within loop.. here is your clean code.
[JS BIN](https://jsbin.com/numukanuxa/7/edit?html,output)

```
<div style="float:left;width:30%;padding:30px;">
    <?php
     $people= get_field('people');
     $a=0;
     foreach ($people as $r) {
    $a++;
    ?>
              <div style="">
                <img src="<?php echo $r['image']['sizes']['team'];?>" style="max-width:750px !important;width:250px;">
                <h3>
                    <?php echo $r['name'];?>
                </h3>
                <div class="position">
                    <?php echo $r['position'];?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $r['intro_text'];?>
                <?php if ($r[ 'learn_more_text']) { ?>
                <a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>">Learn More</a>
                <?php } ?>
     <?php if ($r[ 'learn_more_text']) { ?>
     <div id="<?php echo sanitize_title($r['name'] );?>" class="reveal-modal medium" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">

    <h3><?php echo $r['name'];?></h3>
    <div class="position">
        <?php echo $r['position'];?>
    </div>
    <div class="content">       
    <?php echo $r['learn_more_text'];?>
    </div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
     </div>
            </div>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php } ?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The <div style="clear:both;"></div> helped but the rest of the code didn't.  I need each image to be next to each other.  2-3 per row.  Not aligned vertically.